# What is memory buffer? And how different Scanner class methods operate on the probable issues of line breaks, white spaces etc.?

Tags: java, validation, try-catch, java.util.scanner

I am having trouble understanding how memory buffer works when I am working with `Scanner` class methods such as `hasNextInt()` `hasNextDouble()` etc. Considering the following code,

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
int number;
do {
  System.out.print("Enter a positive integer: ");
  while (!in.hasNextInt()) {
      System.out.println("It's not an integer!");
      in.next();
  }
  number = in.nextInt();
} while (number <= 0);
System.out.println("Your number is " + number);
```

The output for some random values:

```
Enter a positive integer: five
It's not an integer!
-1
Enter a positive integer: 45
Your number is 45
```

What actually happens here? At *line 1* when I enter `five` the nested `while` loop runs. What is the job of `in.next()`? After I enter `five` it says *It's not an integer!* But why doesn't it ask again: *Enter a positive integer:* ? Basically, I want the corresponding output to be like this:

```
Enter a positive integer: five
It's not an integer!
Enter a positive integer: -1
It's not a positive integer!
Enter a positive integer: 45
Your number is 45.
```

I would appreciate a brief and intuitive explanation how `white spaces`, `line breaks` are handled in input validation? And what is memory buffer? And how different methods of `Scanner` class like `next()`, `nextLine()`, `nextInt()`, `nextDouble()` etc. operate?
Also, how do I avoid repetition of *It's not an integer!*

```
Enter a positive number: five
It's not an integer!
one two three
It's not an integer!
It's not an integer!
It's not an integer!
10
Your number is 10
```

And finally, why many recommend `try` `catch`?

Comment: In general these kind of questions are best answered by running the code in a debugger. Have you tried running the above in a debugger?

Comment: Additionally the Scanner documentation explains what each of those functions do. Do you have a specific query about the docuentation?

Comment: No, I am sorry, actually I am new in Java. So I am facing some difficulties understanding these concepts.

Answer (score 1):

To start with, **0**, **-1**, **-66**, **2352**, **+66**, are all Integer values so you can't very well decide to designate them as otherwise. Your validation response should really be:

```
System.out.println("It's not a positive integer value!");
```

I personally never use those **nextInt()**, **nextDouble()**, etc methods unless I want blind validation. I just stick with a single loop, and utilize the **nextLine()** method along with the [String#matches()](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_string_matches.htm) method (with a small [Regular Expression](https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaRegularExpressions/article.html)). I also don't really care for using a **try/catch** to solve a situation where I don't have to.

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
int number = 0;
while (number < 1) {
    System.out.print("Enter a positive integer (q to quit): ");
    String str = in.nextLine();
    if (!str.equals("") && String.valueOf(str.charAt(0)).equalsIgnoreCase("q")) {
        System.exit(0);
    }
    // If a string representation of a positive Integer value 
    // is supplied (even if it's prefixed with the '+' character) 
    // then convert it to Integer.
    if (str.matches("\\+?\\d+") && !str.equals("0")) {
        number = Integer.parseInt(str);
    }
    // Otherwise...
    else {
        System.err.println(str + " is not considered a 'positive' integer value!");
    }
} 
System.out.println("Your number is " + number);
```

In this particular use-case, I actually find this more versatile but then, perhaps that's just me. It doesn't matter what is entered, you will always get a response of one form or another and, you have a quit option as well. To quit either the word `quit` or the letter `q` (in any letter case) can be supplied.

People like to utilize the **try/catch** in case a **NumberFormatException** is thrown by **nextInt()** because a white-space or any character other than a digit is supplied. This then allows the opportunity of displaying a message to console that an invalid input was supplied.

Because the **Scanner** class is passed **System.in** within its' constructor (**in** is an object of **InputStream**) it is a Stream mechanism and therefore contains a input (holding) buffer. When anything is typed to the Console Window it is place within the input buffer until the buffer is read by any one of the **next...()** methods.

***Not all*** Scanner class methods like **next()**, **nextInt()**, **nextDouble()**, etc, completely utilize everything contained within the stream input buffer, for example, these methods do not consume whitespaces, tabs, and any newline characters when the <kbd>ENTER</kbd> key is hit. The **nextLine()** method however does consume everything within the input buffer.

This is exactly why when you have a prompt for a User to supply an Integer value (age) and you use the **nextInt()** method to get that data and then directly afterwords you prompt for a string like the User's name using the **nextLine()** method, you will notice that the **nextLine()** prompt is skipped over. This is because there is still a newline character within the input buffer that wasn't consumed by the **nextInt()** method and now forces the **nextLine()** method to consume it. That <kbd>ENTER</kbd> that was done in the previous **nextInt()** method is now passed into the nextLine() method thus giving the impression that the prompt was bypassed when in reality, it did receive a newline character (which in most cases is pretty much useless).

To overcome this particular situation the easiest thing to do is to consume the <kbd>ENTER</kbd> key newline character by adding `scanner.nextLine();` directly after a `int myVar = scanner.nextInt();` call. This then empties the input buffer before the `String name = scanner.nextLine();` comes into play.